# How do I check if a word is present in the classname?

Tags: java, css, selenium, classname

I'm trying to validate whether the string ("Pre laminated ") is is the css class name I'm trying to check.

I don't want to print the entire text in classname, just validate whether the given word is in the Classname or not: Print "pass" if the word exists, print "fail" if the word doesn't.

Comment: No need to check, a class name certainly won't contain that string

Comment: There can't be spaces in class names so it definitely can't be that

Comment: @Bohemian actually, you are wrong, because spaces are allowed in classname. In css

Comment: @SemyonDanilov ah! I see now - being a java guy and the question tagged java I assumed wrong context. Thanks for pointing that out (+1)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are talking about CSS classes, so thats the answer:

```
WebElement element = ...;
String className = element.getAttribute("class");
if (className.contains("Pre laminated")) {
    LOGGER.log("pass");
} else {
    LOGGER.log("fail");
}
```